# Save multiple row data and some other data into two tables simultaneously in spring hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to save data of a form into two tables simultaneously. The form contains multiple identical rows with some fields like

> item, unit, unit_price, total.

**1.)** In the table1 I would like to save some data like id(auto generated, primary key), date, creator.

**2.)** In table2 I would like to save the id(auto generated, primary key), fid(id of the table1, foreign key), item, unit, unit price, total. Remember, in table2 multiple rows will be save from the form data.

I can't figure it out. Please help me with a valid step by step example, and please don't use static or pre-defined data, take the data from form only.

Answer (score 0):

Is your form an HTML form on a web page, and are you writing a Spring MVC application?  Have you setup Spring Security, or some other authentication mechanism such that you know who the user is?  If so, here is one approach:

- Define a plain old Java object (POJO) with fields id, unit, unit-price, total, creator, currentDate; perhaps you would name it Item.
- Define another plain old Java object perhaps named "ItemHistory", with its own ID and a reference to an Item.
- In the first POJO ("Item") include a reference to a list of ItemHistorys.
- Annotate both classes with Hibernate/JPA annotations, such that the Item has a OneToMany relationship to ItemHistory.
- Define a Spring MVC controller with a method annotated as a POST method, with an Item as one parameter, and an Authentication as another parameter (supposing you have configured Spring Security, the Authentication will automatically be populated with the identity of the currently-logged-in user.  In this method, set the currentDate and author of the Item to the current date and the principal from the Authentication parameter.  If it is a new Item (no id yet), add the first ItemHistory as a copy of the Item itself.  If it is an existing item, add another ItemHistory if needed.
- Define a Spring bean, perhaps named ItemService, with a method annotated as transactional, that takes an Item and saves it.  Call this bean from the REST controller.  Such a Spring bean is known as a DAO (data access object).

There are other strategies, but if you already have Spring MVC, Spring Security, and Hibernate/JPA configured to your needs, this one is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: The form is a html from on a web page and I am writing a spring mvc application. I have two POJO class, one is BudgetMaster containing (id, date and creator) fields and another is BudgetSummery containing (id, fid, item_id, unit, unit_price, total) fields. Yes it has one to many relationship. Can you provide any working sample code??

Comment: Which aspect do you need a working sample for - the JPA annotations?  The spring security configuration?  The controller / DAO interaction?  All these, or something else?

Comment: The controller / DAO interaction with hibernate

Comment: Well, here is our typical controller code... sorry, I'm having a hard time with Stack Overflow comments.  Will try adding a new answer.

Comment: Typical controller code I use is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb41b7ae32777f78297e8ad504ecf22c.  I use XML configuration, so we would have an XML file that injects the SaveItemService.  Will post more in a minute... I hope it will help.

Comment: Spring XML config for the Java I posted above is here: https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/43307dcc258565ec1e352a6fbef32890.  You probably already know Spring MVC sets up its own Spring context, so if you use XML config, you have to load the MVC controller configs in the MVC application context, versus the base Spring app context...

Comment: ... I should mention that the controller depends on Spring message conversion, that is how the controller can accept an Item as a parameter, and return an Item.  The HTML form should have form fields that match the field names in the Java Item class.

Comment: Gist for the save item service: https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/07927b2bee469a035721898f8210b30a.  The @PersistenceContext field is wired automatically by Spring based on your JPA configuration... let me know if you need an example of JPA config.  I'll post the Spring XML for the save item service in a bit.

Comment: The save item service bean would actually be a pretty simple bean definition in XML, since in this example it doesn't have any special properties, something like this: `<bean id="saveItemService" class="com.sample.service.SaveItemService"/>`

Comment: Let me know whether I hit the mark with these snippets, or if you were really looking for something else.